# How to use groupby with LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am new to C#.For my assignment,I have to display movie which are groupedby ratings(5 to 1)  from the list.

I used the following query but the loop is giving my Argument

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();

var sorted = from c in mediaInv 
             where c.MediaType == "Movie" 
             group c by c.Rating into movieRankings
             orderby movieRankings descending 
             select movieRankings;

//argumentexception here
foreach (var x in sorted)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(x.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need just sort from 5 to 1 rating?

```
var sorted = from c in mediaInv 
             where c.MediaType == "Movie" 
             orderby c.Rating descending 
             select c;
```

I don't understand, why you need grouping.
You can group items by rating, but every group can contain many fils. So, what are you going to do with these groups? Just show them in rating descending order? So, use sort.

Comment: This maybe it.Got confused because description says group by ratings(5 to 1).Anyway,I have used the solution you provided.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Argh, for me personally, `GroupBy` is easier to understand when I use the lambda expressions.

```
listBox1.Items.Clear();

var sorted = mediaInv.GroupBy(k => k.Rating, v=>v)
    .OrderByDescending(kv => kv.Key)
    .ToList();

//argumentexception here
foreach (var x in sorted)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(x.Key.ToString());
}
```

So basically, `x` is going to be a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. So it will have a `.Key` and a `.Value` that you will need to use.